# SQL - Identify Continuous groups of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, dense-rank

For a table like below, the need is to identify continuous occurrence of a certain value in Column D. I have a C# script which performs this, but would be great if there's a query (or two-three, based on temp tables) that could accomplish this.

Column C : Can have only 0 or 1

```
SELECT   Column A,
         Column B,
         Column C
FROM     Table
ORDER BY Column A,
         Column B
```

Sample Table Data:

```
Column A,Column B,Column C
Employee 1,Value 1,0
Employee 1,Value 2,0
Employee 1,Value 3,0
Employee 1,Value 4,1
Employee 1,Value 5,1
Employee 1,Value 6,1
Employee 1,Value 7,0
Employee 1,Value 8,0
Employee 1,Value 9,1
Employee 1,Value 10,1
Employee 1,Value 11,1
Employee 1,Value 12,1
```

Expected result (EDIT: Made minor change in Column C):

```
Column A, Start Value, End Value, Column C
Employee 1, Value 1, Value 1, 0
Employee 1, Value 2, Value 2, 0
Employee 1, Value 3, Value 3, 0
Employee 1, Value 4, Value 6, 3
Employee 1, Value 7, Value 7, 0
Employee 1, Value 8, Value 8, 0
Employee 1, Value 9, Value 12, 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the difference in row numbers.  Run the subquery to see how this works:

```
select a, c, min(b), max(b)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum_a,
             row_number() over (partition by a, c order by b) as seqnum_ac
      from t
     ) t
group by a, c, (seqnum_a - seqnum_ac);
```

Comment: This is great, I can definitely build on this! Thanks. The only place I'm correcting on this is:
1. The Column C should be grouped only on 1s while 0s should be retained individually
2. One thing I mis-stated on the result was that: The Column C on result should read 3 & 4 for Row 4 and Row 7 (the sum of 1s)

Comment: select a, SUM(c), min(b), max(b)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum_a,
             row_number() over (partition by a, c order by b) as seqnum_ac
      from t
     ) t
group by a, c, CASE WHEN c=0 THEN seqnum_a ELSE (seqnum_a - seqnum_ac) END;

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you explain / point some source to understand better this "difference in row numbers" method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn . . . It really helps if you look at the results of the subquery.